# Unit Tests - where to place initialization code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I like to have unit tests which are small and just have the call to the function under test and Asserts.

But I am confused about where to place the initialization code? There are a lot of variables like request/response objects and others which are used by the unit tests. There are a couple of ways to initialize them.

1. Initialize them inside test itself, but that results in tests getting huge
2. Have a setUp() or initialize() which has the initialization stuff, this results in number of private class variables, but seems better than other 2 since all the initialization code is in one place.
3. Have private methods to do that, results in lot of private methods, sometimes 1 test needs 2-3 private methods.

Can any one point to which approach is better? Also any references to some good writeups on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Have a setUp() or initialize() which has the initialization stuff, this results in number of private class variables, but seems better than other 2 since all the initialization code is in one place.

You should place your initialization code in methods annotated with @Before and @BeforeClass annotations. Using this convention every other developer will not be surprised and will find quickly what he wants. Notice that it doesn't mean you shouldn't create private methods in JUnit tests. When your setup() method will eventually became large you might consider splitting it by logical parts of code into private methods.

I found [this site](http://www.kyleblaney.com/junit-best-practices/) helpful when it comes to briefly describing good practices in JUnit.

Comment: I generally place the initialization code in @Before. But in certain cases there are tests which are testing the same function for some "success/failure" condition with different input's. So for each test I need to initialize the input's. Which can make the test's relatively large.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Enclosed feature available in JUnit. Using this we can group tests related into static inner class and can have common setUp for related tests. If we have some variables common across all tests, we can put in the outer class. Look at [this](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/'Enclosed'-test-runner-example) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Organising your tests in a clear and tidy way is not easy, and it will heavily depend on your context. But there are a couple of things that you should consider:

- Initialisation code that is common to all your test cases should be in the @Before or @BeforeClass methods. In particular, you should use the latter for computationally expensive code, like connecting to a database.
- Initialisation code that is specific to each test case should be in the test case itself. Use patterns to simplify the setup for each test, like the [ObjectMother](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) or the [Test Data Builder](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestDataBuilder).

I do not particularly like having private helper methods inside the tests, although in some specific situations I found them useful. But I would rather create a separate helper class (some kind of builder, most likely) that can be reused in other places.

Hope this helps.